# UIKit.UISceneSessionActivationRequest not available error in GitHub actions for publishing .NET MAUI

Tags: github-actions, maui, testflight

I've been using the following GitHub action to publish my .NET MAUI app to TestFlight and it's been working fine. Today, I got this error:

> The type 'UIKit.UISceneSessionActivationRequest' (used as a parameter
> in UIKit.UIApplication.ActivateSceneSession) is not available in iOS
> 16.2 (it was introduced in iOS 17.0). Please build with a newer iOS SDK (usually done by using the most recent version of Xcode).

I'm using the latest version of MacOS -- see below -- in my GitHub action.

Also, as per code changes in my app, I'm not really introducing anything new. Some bug fixes and a couple of new pages that just make API calls and display data in `CollectionView`'s. So, I'm not really doing anything new or fancy with this version. This version is targeting .NET 8 but I was even able to publish a version of my app targeting .NET 8 RC2 using this GitHub action.

Here's my GitHub action YAML:

```
name: Build & Publish My .NET MAUI iOS App

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build-pack-n-ship:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 8.0.x
    - name: Install MAUI workload
      run: dotnet workload install maui
    - name: Import Code-Signing Certificates
      uses: Apple-Actions/import-codesign-certs@v1
      with:
        p12-filepath: 'MyAppleDistributionCert.p12'
        p12-password: ${{ secrets.CERTIFICATES_P12_PASSWORD }}
    - name: Download Apple Provisioning Profiles
      uses: Apple-Actions/download-provisioning-profiles@v1
      with:
        bundle-id: 'myapp.mydomain.com'
        issuer-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_ISSUER_ID }}
        api-key-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_KEY_ID }}
        api-private-key: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build and Publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -f:net8.0-ios /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true /p:EnableAssemblyILStripping=false
    - name: List generated files
      run: ls -l
    - name: Upload Build Artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3.0.0
      with:
        path: '**/*.ipa'
    - name: 'Upload app to TestFlight'
      uses: apple-actions/upload-testflight-build@v1
      with: 
        app-path: './MyApp/bin/Release/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/publish/MyApp.ipa'
        issuer-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_ISSUER_ID }}
        api-key-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_KEY_ID }}
        api-private-key: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it:

First, I changed the masOS version to `runs-on: macos-13`.

Then I added a step to pick the latest version of Xcode by adding the following:

```
- uses: maxim-lobanov/setup-xcode@v1
      with:
        xcode-version: latest
```

BTW, I didn't use `xcode-version: latest-stable` which allows me to use the beta version of Xcode 15.

Here's the updated version of my YAML:

```
name: Build & Publish My .NET MAUI iOS App

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build-pack-n-ship:

    runs-on: macos-13

    steps:
    - uses: maxim-Lobanov/setup-xcode@v1
      with:
        xcode-version: latest
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 8.0.x
    - name: Install MAUI workload
      run: dotnet workload install maui
    - name: Import Code-Signing Certificates
      uses: Apple-Actions/import-codesign-certs@v1
      with:
        p12-filepath: 'MyAppleDistributionCert.p12'
        p12-password: ${{ secrets.CERTIFICATES_P12_PASSWORD }}
    - name: Download Apple Provisioning Profiles
      uses: Apple-Actions/download-provisioning-profiles@v1
      with:
        bundle-id: 'myapp.mydomain.com'
        issuer-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_ISSUER_ID }}
        api-key-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_KEY_ID }}
        api-private-key: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY }}
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build and Publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -f:net8.0-ios /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true /p:EnableAssemblyILStripping=false
    - name: List generated files
      run: ls -l
    - name: Upload Build Artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3.0.0
      with:
        path: '**/*.ipa'
    - name: 'Upload app to TestFlight'
      uses: apple-actions/upload-testflight-build@v1
      with: 
        app-path: './MyApp/bin/Release/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/publish/MyApp.ipa'
        issuer-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_ISSUER_ID }}
        api-key-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_KEY_ID }}
        api-private-key: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

IMPORTANT: Changing only the `macos-version` to 13 did not work because there seems to be multiple versions of Xcode in the image -- see: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/macos-13/20231025.2/images/macos/macos-13-Readme.md

Thanks to these devs here for guiding me through this process: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18632#issuecomment-1817943549

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the runs-on: macos-13 change. Yeesh, why can't they just update AppCenter to do this? It used to be so easy...